# How to use Snowflake Stored Procedure in SSRS Query

Tags: stored-procedures

I have an SMS (SQL) Stored Procedure that was converted in Snowflake, but i am not able to see the dataset field listing after i called the Snowflake stored procedure.

From SMS (SQL) Stored Procedure

```
EXEC USP_REPORTS_CCP_KVPMAP_INTERVAL
```

From Snowflake Stored Procedure

```
CALL CDW_PRD_CALL_DB.CDW_CONTACTCENTER_RPT_SC.USP_REPORTS_CCP_KVPMAP_INTERVAL(:STARTDATE,:ENDDATE,:INCLUDE_CONSULTS,:0);
```

All, i am seeing in the Dataset section on the left is the Stored Procedure name from Snowflake? How can I call a snowflake stored procedure and display the data set fields in ssrs?